# How to pull notebooks from github to google cloud datalab?

Tags: python, google-cloud-datalab

I can connect with my instance through `datalab connect sample-lab`, how to pull my notebooks in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the built-in `ungit` client. Click on its icon in the top right toolbar, it looks like this: [image]. This wil take you to the ungit interface, where you can clone your notebooks from any github address.

Alternatively, you can clone them from any notebook cell by running a bash command:

`!git clone https://github.com/my/notebooks/repo`

Comment: Thank you, I watched "Intro to ungit" and managed to clone my repo.